# Refresh TextView while typing a EditText

Tags: android, textwatcher

I'm building a a checkout activity, the user Input the values (Number) inside one or more EditText. In the bottom of the activity I need to update the total value with the sum of all EditText.

I've tried to use the TextWatcher like this:

```
  @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable arg0) {
            if(!arg0.toString().equals(current)){
                        String bottom_value = total_value.getText().toString();
                        String number_total  = bottom_value.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");//remove $
                        String value_arg = arg0.toString();
                        String number_arg  = value_arg.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");//remove $

                        int final_int = Integer.parseInt(number_arg)+ Integer.parseInt(number_total);
                        total_value.setText(Integer.toString(final_int)); 
            }
        }
```

But the problem is when the user type more than 1 number.If you type 1 than 2, the final value need to be 12 but with my code it's 3(sum of 1 and 2).

Sorry about my english, if you don't understand something comment and I can explain better.

[image: HERE] is a example of my app.

Comment: Post your complete code so people can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace this

```
 int final_int = Integer.parseInt(number_arg)+ Integer.parseInt(number_total);
```

by this

```
 int final_int = Integer.parseInt(number_arg+number_total);
```